# Passing `[]` as a part of command line argument for CLI go program

Tags: go

I have written a go generator that helps with creating handlers for routers.

Here is an example of the current syntax

```
//go:generate flow -handler=CreateProjectStaffAssignmentsHandler -params=StaffList:peopledata.ProjectStaffMember -router=PeopleRouter -url=create-project-staff-assignments
```

This code generates the a struct for POST params

```
type createProjectStaffAssignmentsParams struct {
    StaffList peopledata.ProjectStaffMember
}
```

...and the body of the handler

```
func (rt *PeopleRouter) CreateProjectStaffAssignmentsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    logger, as := routeutils.InitReporter(w, "CreateProjectStaffAssignmentsHandler")

    var params createProjectStaffAssignmentsParams
    err := as.Decode(r, logger, &params)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
// Other things
    as.JSONBody = staff
    data, err := as.Write(true, "ok")
    logger.LogActionStatus(data, err)
}
```

`flow` is a simple CLI that use `flag` package to accept and parse command line arguments.

The challenge arises when I try to generate arrays.

I seem not to be able to do `-params=StaffList:[]peopledata.ProjectStaffMember` because `handlerParams := *flag.String("params", "", "Params struct for decoding data")` does not allow for `[]`.

Any thoughts on how I could work around this?

Comment: Have you tried `-params='StaffList:[]peopledata.ProjectStaffMember'`?

Comment: Yes. Thats fails and results in an error. I feel this may be a limitation of of the shell

Comment: just to make one point clear: `flow` is the tool you wrote, is that correct ? you have control over its source code ?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/YtAYpB9bXXO the `flag` package does accept any string (even if it contains `[]`). The issue is probably linked to how that value is handled afterwards in the `flow` program, or perhaps in the way some characters are handled by the shell that executes your command. Can you please provide more info on the error, or on the code of your helper program ? can you also specify what OS you are running ?

Comment: @LeGEC: I wrote flow and have full control over the source. I'm on Mac OS. I think the issue is that the shell doesn't allow for `[]` as a part of command line argument.

Comment: @LeGEC the param is defined like this
`handlerParams := flag.String("params", "", "Params struct for decoding data")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention in your comments that you are in full control for the code of your generator, and that the issue is a quoting issue in your command line.

Here are two suggestions to work around that:

1. change the syntax for your generator, so that it doesn't require you to use characters that are tricky on a command line :

```
... -params=StaffList:peopledata.ProjectStaffMember_slice ...
// or
... -params=StaffList:arr_peopledata.ProjectStaffMember ...
// and adapt the code of your parser accordingly
```

2. get a clearer undestanding of what shell gets used to execute your `go:generate` instructions, and try an appropriate level of quoting/escaping:

```
// blind suggestions from usually known ways to escape a command line string:

//go:generate flow ... -params='StaffList:[]model.People'
//go:generate flow ... "-params='StaffList:[]model.People'"
//go:generate flow ... -params=StaffList:\[\]model.People
...

// perhaps look deeper into the documentation of go:generate escaping ?
```

Comment: I like the suggestion of the _slice!